# Finding the inverse of a function in Python (possibly using SymPy)

Tags: python, function, sympy

Is there a way to find the inverse of a function in Python? For example, if I have the function `def f(x): return x**2`, is there a function in Python/any Python library function that does this? Or is it just too hard, or even unsolvable for computers?

Comment: This library will calculate the numerical inverse of invertible functions: https://pypi.org/project/pynverse/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the inverse of `f(x)` is `i` then solving `f(x) - i` for x gives you the inverse. So

```
>>> from sympy import solve
>>> from sympy.abc import i, x
>>> solve(x**2 - i, x)
[-sqrt(i), sqrt(i)]
```

So for that function there are two branches for a given `i`.

Comment: How solving (f-i=0) can return i the inverse function of f? The trick is not easy to understand.

Comment: If `f(x) = 2*x` whose inverse if `F(i) = i/2` (or `F(x) = x/2`, if you prefer), then `sol = solve(2*x - i, x, dict=True)[0] -> {x: i/2}` which is `F(i)`, the inverse. If you want it to have `x` instead of `i`, do `sol[x].subs(i, x) -> x/2`.

Comment: I got it somehow, you solve `x = i(f(x)` with `solve (2*x - i, ...)` which means `2*x - i` == `0`, and express the root `i = 2x` as a function of `x`:  `x = i/2`. And indeed it works well for other expressions. Thanks.

Comment: Very simple actually!

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the game here, but don't forget there are different kinds of inverses. The accepted answer gives the additive inverse, but you would solve for the multiplicative inverse as:

```py
import sympy as sp

x = sp.Symbol("x")
f = x**2                           # define the function
fInv = sp.Symbol("f^-1")           # define a symbol for the inverse
inv = sp.solve(f * fInv - 1, fInv) # solve for f * fInv == 1
sp.pprint(inv)
```

Which outputs:

```
⎡1 ⎤
⎢──⎥
⎢ 2⎥
⎣x ⎦
```

Comment: If you want the multiplicative inverse of `f(x)` there is no need for `solve`: the answer is `1/f(x)`. The OP wanted to know how to find the inverse function `F` for a given function `f` such that `F(f(x)) = x`.